# Accessing properties of objects in D3 histogram bins

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm working on a D3.js project to display a histogram of some student test results pulled from a CSV file. In addition to the raw test scores I also have some other demographic data about each student in the CSV. I'd like to be able to mouse over any particular bar in the histogram and display some summary statistics about the students who are represented in that bar.

Is it possible to access the other attributes of the records that are contained in the arrays that constitute the histogram bars? If so, does anyone know of an example I can inspect?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [histogram](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout#wiki-histogram) layout throws everything except the scalars used to create the histogram bins.

There might be a better way of doing this, but since the other student attributes aren't attached to each bar, just search the original array of students for those whose scores are in the moused over bin:

```
.on('mouseover',function(d){ 
  console.log('data bound to bars ' + d); 
  var selectedStudents = values.filter(function(record){
            return d.x <= record.score && record.score < d.x + d.dx; });
  console.log(selectedStudents.map(function(record){ return record.name; }));
});
```

http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/6568151

The selectedStudents array can be used to generate other summary statistics besides listing off names.

Answer (score 1):

You can display tooltip on top of bar chart during mouseover event. The idea is to make a div float on top of svg area. You can display various information within tooltip. See example here:

http://vida.io/documents/F3Ehr3qqeK28P22wn

Here's the block of code that show/hide tooltip:

```
on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var bar_width = parseInt($(this).attr("width"), 10);
    var x = parseInt($(this).attr("x"), 10) + bar_width / 2 + 5;
    var y = parseInt($(this).attr("y"), 10) - 20;
    div.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 1);
    // include info you want to display here:
    div.html(d[X_AXIS_COLUMN] + "<br/>" + Y_DATA_FORMAT(d[Y_AXIS_COLUMN])).style("left", x + "px").style("top", y + "px");
}).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've imported the full csv (or at least all the data you need from it), use d3.bins() to "bin" the data for your histogram.

d3.bins has an accessor function: .value() which you can use like so:

```
const myBinFunction = d3.bins().value((d)=> {return d.propertyToBinDataBy})
const myBinnedData = myBinFunction(myData) 
// myData presumes an array of objects
```

...myBinnedData now contains all of the object data you started with, now sorted into bins, given by the property you specified in myBinFunction.

You can use this array of arrays of binned data to draw your histogram (using whatever method you're currently using) and provide relevant tooltip info on mouseover.

Appreciate it's an old question, but I found it when making [my own histogram](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-viz-practice-sfts04?file=/src/histo.jsx) and running into just this issue, so hopefully this of use to others out there.

[The docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#bins) are worth checking too...